# Chakra nature of Tailed Beasts

Tags: naruto

As we all know that *Kurama's chakra* is of the **healing nature type**. This is known from many mentions about it in the wiki page of [Naruto Uzumaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki).

My question is, what is the nature type of the chakra of the other Tailed beasts?

*Note: This is my thinking why there should have been a nature type to each of the tailed beasts.*

As we all know that when *Rikudō Sennin* was about to die, he split his powers among his two sons (the older son inherited his powerful chakra and spiritual energy, and the younger son inherited his powerful life force and physical energy). Similarly, when creating the nine tailed beasts from the *Shinju*, he must have split the chakra based on their nature so that each tailed beast had a unique natured chakra.

Any insight on this would be very much welcomed.

Comment: He did not split his chakra between his sons for any reason, they Inherited opposite halves of his power (just enough of it that combineing the 2 would result in the rinnegan). it was when he was about to die that he split the 10 tails into the 9 tailed beasts, though even that did not kill him and he was rendered immobile for a few days.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A few facts first:

- Kurama's chakra isn't healing type. Minato sealed Yang-Kurama in Naruto, which resulted in the chakra Kurama gave him to be Yang oriented. This adds the healing properties to that chakra.
- Not all tailed beasts have a known nature, but some do.

So the natures:

- **Shukaku** - Wind, evident by the [Drilling Air Bullet](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Release%3a_Drilling_Air_Bullet) he fired at Gamabunta.
- **Matatabi** - Fire, evident by the [fireball](http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110118223552/naruto/images/6/62/Two-Tail_Fire_Blast.JPG) she fired at Hidan and Kakuzu when they battled her.
- **Isobu** - Water, obvious.
- **Son Goku** - Lava (Earth and Fire), evident by multiple lava techniques reanimated Roshi used while in Jinchuuriki form.
- **Kokuo** - Not revealed. His Jinchuuriki was said to use the Steam element (Fire and Water)
- **Saiken** - Not revealed. His Jinchuuriki uses Water element and specializes in bubbles. Saiken himself was shown to be able to spit acid.
- **Chomei** - Not revealed. Not much was revealed about its Jinchuuriki too.
- **Gyuuki** - Not revealed, but presumed Lightning. His Jinchuuriki uses Lightning.
- **Kurama** - Not revealed, but presumed Yin-Yang. His Jinchuuriki was shown to have remarkable stamina and healing properties, which suggest Yang nature which is compatible with the half of Kurama he had. The other half's chakra was not explained thoroughly.
- Last but not least

  > **Shinju** (God Tree; Juubi) - Natural Energy and Yin-Yang. Evident by the techniques Obito uses after becoming its Jinchuuriki, as well as what was revealed in the manga.

Comment: @R.J: Well, Yang is the nature of life and vitality, and it was also hinted that healing techniques were utilizing the Yang element. Aside from that, Kurama never did anything that has to do with healing (in fact, his chakra was usually full of hate and even poisonous). It's really a collection of hints, more than it was explicitly stated in the manga/anime.

Comment: Wait, does a Jinchuuriki gain the nature of his/her tailed beast? And if so, does the tailed beast gain the nature of its Jinchuuriki?

Comment: @TAAPSogeking, I think that would be a different question.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, you can include that Chōmei is an insect type like the Aburame clan.

Comment: Insect isn't a type. This is Naruto not Pokemon.

Comment: I knew that it is not actually the *"insect-type"* I am referring to like pokemon but it is worth mentioning though. Just suggesting since you can't classify those as an *element* per se.

Comment: Well the question IS about chakra nature... :-)

Comment: So is Chomei weak against Matatabi? LOL

Comment: There was one filler episode with Fū in second Chūnin exam, I forgot if  they shown Chomei's power or not

Comment: Recall that Shukaku can do Magnet Style as well. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art:_Magnet_Release_Rasengan

Answer (score 2):

- Shukaku: wind and earth via magnet style.
- Matatabi: signature blue fire style.
- Isobu: water style / coral production
- Son Goku: earth and fire via lava style
- Kokuo: fire and water via vapor style
- Saiken: alkali acid secretion
- Chomei: most likely wind style and scale production
- Gyuki: ink production
- Kurama: negative emotion sensing, rapid healing rate, and possibly fire and wind style
- Shinju: all 5 chakra natures along with yin and yang style, all elemental kekkei genkai, wood style, Rinne Sharingan, and comprised of nature energy

Answer (score 0):

Kurama Might actually have Lightning, Fire and Wind... 
I don't really remember some of the other tailed beast names...

One tail: Magnet, since it uses sand,which I am thinking is a combination between wind and crystal/earth style

Two Tails: Blue Fire, her body looks like it's made of fire and she uses fire when attacking

Three tails: Water, he is from the Mist village, and is a giant turtle... that's kind of obvious xD

Four Tails(Son Goku): Lava Style,

Five Tails:Boil, or Steam style, Water and Fire

Six Tails:Water style, he(I think it's a he) uses bubble style

Seven Tails(Chomei): All I really know is that he looks like  a Beetle with seven wings attached to his rear end >.>

Eight Tails(Gyuki): Ink, and since he's an octopus, I am thinking possibly water as well

Answer (score -1):

Naruto is able to make different types of Rasengans using the other Tailed Beast's chakra inside of him. But when he does this technique against Kaguya, the Rasenshuriken he uses from Kuruma is just wind style. I think it's safe to say Kuruma possesses a strong wind style based chakra, which is why Naruto also is able to use strong wind style. The healing powers Naruto possesses comes from Kuruma's yang half, simply because his yang half possesses so much life force, that it heals Naruto at a faster rate.