# Does a Jinchuuriki gain the nature of his/her tailed beast?

Tags: naruto

I find this question interesting here: [Chakra nature of Tailed Beasts](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5671/chakra-nature-of-tailed-beasts).

And I saw the comment: *Does a Jinchuuriki gain the nature of his/her tailed beast? And if so, does the tailed beast gain the nature of its Jinchuuriki?*

So to confirm this, I ask a different question.

Comment: I would ask a similar question. +1.

Comment: The answer should be yes... unless someone can give a counter example. Every Jinchuuriki can use attacks from the Bijuu.

Comment: i think it's yes, what is that black-liquid type technique obito used when he absorbed the juubi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it has some sort of influence, but is not absolute:

### Example pro:

- Roshi, Son Goku's Jinchuuriki, uses lava similarly to the bijuu.
- Gaara, Shukaku's Jinchuuriki uses sand much like Shukaku himself (although it was later revealed to be Gaara's mother).

### Example against:

- Naruto, Kurama's Jinchuuriki, has Wind as his main element, but Kurama has not shown using Wind at all.

I do believe the bijuu has some sort of influence on the Jinchuuriki's chakra development, especially if they're sealed in them when they are very young. (Naruto's chakra alone was said to be at least 4 times in amount that of Kakashi).

As for whether the Jinchuuriki's chakra is the same the bijuu, I don't think so. It's more dependant on genes, etc.

Comment: I don't think your Example against really applies to this question : Does the Jin gain the nature of the Bijuu. Shinobi can have multiple affinities and even though Kurama doesn't have wind type, Naruto can still gain his bijuu's chakra in addition to his wind type.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that has ever occurred or will occur in future.

Tailed beast are dependent on the Jinchuuriki for existence and lend Jinchuuriki's chakra whenever required, Its never the other way around.

> [If the tailed beast is removed from its jinchūriki's body, the jinchūriki will die. Similarly, if the jinchūriki dies with the tailed beast still sealed within them, the beast will die too. Because of this, the tailed beasts tend to be very protective of their jinchūriki, and will take any action whenever their lives are in danger.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jinch%C5%ABriki#cite_ref-12)

They are not good at controlling their own chakra, so I dont think they will be able to control or manipulate any Jinchuuriki's chakra.

> [Although the Ten-Tails possesses great power, much like the other tailed beasts it is unable to use it effectively due to not having enough intelligence to focus its power without being under someone else's control.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shinju#cite_ref-19)

Comment: first, the tailed beasts will not die if its jinchuuriki dies. second, how do you explain where did Obito learn that black-liquid type technique, i think's thats one of the ten-tailed beasts nature.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Bijuu will die if the Jinchuuriki dies. That is why Kurama has provided Naruto with chakra in the past, before they got along, like when Naruto was thrown off that cliff and had to summon Boss Toad. The only way out is if the seal is weakened and the Bijuu can escape death before the human dies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be plain and simple : Yes, the jinchuuriki gains the nature of his or her bijuu. It doesn't change the jinchuuriki's nature, instead it just adds another affinity. If you had the water affinity, and you have a fire bijuu, then now you can use water and fire as well as the combination of water+fire together in a technique.

Naruto is naturally a wind element shinobi. With the kyuubi inside of him, he can use kyuubi attacks (yin/yang).

It seems like a general rule that once you have something (chakra or body part) of a different nature inside your body, you are able to use attacks of that different nature too. Take Kakuzu as an example. He has multiple affinities due to the fact he stole other people's hearts and stuffed them in his own body.

Having multiple affinities does not necessarily mean they will mix and you can't use them separately. Take Yamato for example, as his affinity is water and earth, which also turns into wood. He can use wood techniques (the combination of the 2), but then also use them individually as he once demonstrated by raising the earth and then creating a waterfall.